# Al hacer un update por post dispara el error: "Undefined variable : id"

Tags: php, formularios

Error:

> Notice: Undefined variable : id in function.php

**index.php**

```
<form method="post" action="#" id="update">
<input type="text" id="id" value="">
<input type="text" id="text" value="">
<input type="text" id="title" value="">
<button id="update">Enviar</button>
</form>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">

$("#update").on('click', function(){
 $.post("function.php", {service:'updateMessages', messageId: $("#messageId").val(), text: $("#text").val(), title: $("#title").val()}, 
    function(data){
        alert("Datos: " + data);
    });
});
</script>
```

**function.php**

```
if($_POST['service']=="updateMessages"){

        if(isset($_POST['messageId'])){
            $id = $mysqli->real_escape_string($_GET['messageId']);
        }

        $query = "UPDATE `messages` SET 
                    `messages_text` = '".$mysqli->real_escape_string($_POST['text'])."', 
                    `messages_title` = '".$mysqli->real_escape_string($_POST['title'])."'
                    WHERE `messages`.`messages_id` = ".$id;


        if(isset($_GET['status'])){
           $query_status = $query."messages_status = '".$mysqli->real_escape_string($_POST['status']);
        }        

        $mysqli->query($query_status);
        die(json_encode(getMessages(),JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE));    
    }
```

Comment: puedes recibir `messageId` y `status` a la misma vez? De donde recibes `status`?

Comment: Por favor agrega todo el codigo relevante para el problema y en su caso la traza del error completo

Comment: @DiegoSagredo Llevé la pregunta a como estaba antes (cuando recibiste las respuestas) con algunas ediciones. En el estado que estaba, sólo se mostraba el mensaje de error, haciendo que no esté claro qué se estaba preguntando. Por favor revisa cómo quedó la pregunta actualmente para verificar si está bien, intentando que sea una pregunta completa y detallada. Más información en [ask].

Answer (score 0):

Tienes `isset($_GET['status])` y deberia ser : `isset($_POST['status'])`

```
if(isset($_POST['status'])){
   $query = $query."messages_status = '".$mysqli->real_escape_string($_POST['status']);
}
```

Y que pasaria si no existe `$_POST['status']`? este error estaria siempre molestando ya que tienes dos valores distintos pero siempre envias uno `$query` y `$query_status`. Debes tratar de mantener siempre la misma variable, sobre todo si condicionas su contenido dependiendo de un valor.. Si ese valor no existe tu contexto cambia. Debes mantener el nombre de la variable y si la condicion se cumple, concatenar posibles más resultados o codigo esperado.

```
$query = $query."messages_status = '".$mysqli->real_escape_string($_POST['status']);
```

**EDIT**

```
if ($_POST['service'] == "updateMessages") {

    if (isset($_POST['messageId'])) {
        $id = $mysqli - > real_escape_string($_POST['messageId']);

        if (isset($_POST['text']) && isset($_POST['title'])) {
            $query = "UPDATE `ayudantee`.`messages` SET 

            `messages`.
            `messages_text` = '".$mysqli->real_escape_string($_POST['
            text '])."',
                `messages`.
            `messages_title` = '".$mysqli->real_escape_string($_POST['
            title '])."'
            WHERE `messages`.
            `messages_id` = ".$id; 
        }


        if (isset($_POST['status'])) {

            $query = "UPDATE `messages` SET 
            messages_status = '".$mysqli->real_escape_string($_POST['
            status '])." 
            WHERE `messages`.
            `messages_id` = ".$id; 
        }

        $mysqli->query($query);
        echo json_encode(getMessages());
    }
}
```

Comment: if(isset($_POST['messageId'])){
            $id = $mysqli->real_escape_string($_POST['messageId']); 
}

resultado es : Notice: Undefined variable : id

Comment: Tambien tienes un $_GET en esa parte del codigo

Comment: @DiegoSagredo Update mi respuesta!, recuerda que no debes ocupar `$_GET` si estas utilizando `method='POST'`

Comment: pero if(isset($_POST['messageId'])){
            $id = $mysqli->real_escape_string($_POST['messageId']); 
        } 
separa...
$query = "la conuslta"

Comment: Esto debe quedar asi @DiegoSagredo edito post

Comment: Gracias sioesi.

Comment: igual esta fallado, el problema es que una variable id

Comment: vamos a un chat?

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/47487/discussion-between-sioesi-and-diego-sagredo).

Comment: Averigua: de donde viene `#messageId` (no existe en el formulario)... de donde viene `status`... ??? ... es `true` si `messageId`, `text` y/o `title` están vacíos ?? (**SI!**)... ademas tiene dos `id="update"` en el formulario...

Comment: Es un formulario! Despues de hablar en el chat resolvimos el error. @DiegoSagredo

Answer (score 0):

Esto se debe a que intentas hacer una `query` con una variable que puede o no existir (ya que está contenida dentro de un if).

Por lo que deberás de inicializarla de alguna manera por defecto para que siempre tenga un valor:

```
$query_status = "aqui la inicializas a tu valor por defecto";

if(isset($_POST['status'])){
       $query_status = $query."messages_status = '".$mysqli->real_escape_string($_POST['status']);
    }      

    $mysqli->query($query_status);
```

Además, ten en cuenta que debes usar `$_POST` en vez de `$_GET` ya que se lo estás indicando en el formulario.

Comment: Seguiría tirando error ya que `query` no existe.

Comment: @sioesi La query existe en su código, yo sólo he copiado las líneas relevantes. Él debería de tener un valor por defecto, por ejemplo la query sola, sin establecer el status o hacer que el php acabase mediante `die` en caso de que la condición no se cumpliera.

Comment: aveces me pongo a buscar detalles minimos, porque muchas veces los OP copian y pegan el codigo que nosotros dejamos como posibles respuestas! por eso te hice el alcance!

Comment: @sioesi Y te lo agradezco mucho. ¿Consideras que debería de añadir más información en la respuesta? Igual no queda demasiado clara.

Comment: mi respuesta propone lo mismo que tu y le explico el error entre `query` y `query_status` más que nada por contexto! te aseguro que las dos son 100% validas! Saludos!